# "send" is undefined? | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

```
const Discord = require ("Discord.js")

exports.exec = async (client, message, args) => { 
  const bug = args.slice().join(" ");
  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}\` Please right, in as much detail about the bug\``);
  const channel = client.channels.get('498750658569306123')
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
  .setColor(0)
  .setDescription(bug)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(`Suggestion by ${message.author.tag} from ${message.guild.name}`)
  channel.send(embed)
```

Error thrown back is:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
 at Object.exports.exec (C:\Users\Cake\Peepo\modules\help\bugreport.js:14:11)`

Everything seems to work fine.. I'm unsure how "`send`" is undefined? Someone care to explain?

Comment: I think it is _channel_ to be undefined, not _send_

Comment: The type error shows, send.. wouldn't it yell if "Channel" was undefined? (I could be wrong)

Comment: the type error says your undefined variable (channel) does not have a property called 'send'

Comment: `channels.get('498750658569306123')` returns `undefined`, so `const channel = undefined; channel.send()` -> `undefined.send()`.. undefined does not have a method called send.

Comment: @Imaginebeingme The error states `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`. This implies the parent (i.e. channel) is undefined. By the way, can you console.log(message) before the `if ` check.

Comment: Since you are saving a const called channel can you get its value at the point of the error ?

Comment: Uh. Yeah guys. I was dumb. I didn't have the bot connected to the support server.. Soooo.. kek? hah. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to find your report channel.

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "report-channel-name-here");
channel.send(embed);
```

if that fails, make sure that your bot can access the channel.